# String set in localStorage gets as object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I've JSON.stringified objects to save in localStorage, but they're retrieved as objects ( "[object Object]" ) that can't be parsed.

Scenario:

The first thing I do is

```
localStorage.clear();
```

I've created 3 objects to load into localStorage as a default. Each object is JSON.stringified and saved with it's own key in localStorage. Then, I use a for loop and localStorage.key(i) to get the key and retrieve the objects (strings).

```
if (localStorage.length === 0) {

// make 3 objects

console.log(typeof c);        // logs "string"
localStorage.setItem("_fruit", a);
localStorage.setItem("_veggie", b);
localStorage.setItem("_protein", c);
var test = localStorage.key(0);
test = localStorage.getItem(test);
console.log(test);           // logs stringified JSON
}
```

So far so good. Outside the if statement I have:

```
var test = localStorage.key(0);
console.log(test);          // logs correct key
test = localStorage.getItem(test);
console.log(test);          // logs string of object
test = JSON.parse(test);
console.log(test);          // logs object correctly
```

And this also outputs to the DOM fine. But as soon as I comment out

```
// localStorage.clear();
```

To test the retrieval from local storage, I have this problem:

```
var test = localStorage.key(0);
console.log(test);          // logs correct key
test = localStorage.getItem(test);
console.log(test);          // logs "[object Object]"
test = JSON.parse(test);    <------ logs Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
console.log(test);          // code stops above
```

I'm aware there's no guarantee about the order of indexing local storage and that's fine. Using React if that makes a difference.

Comment: I sure that you have mistaken when place object to localstorage, better use one of library to use localstorage as object storage, or at least write one, and use it everywhere in your code.

Comment: I'll do whatever workaround I need, but there's no reason why this shouldn't work as written, is there? I'd rather keep it simpler.

Comment: make a full sample, if there is not allowed, use plnkr or jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/asparism/Lr0foyLt/ -- uncomment `localStorage.clear();` in getInitialState. the lines i'm indicating are firstly 28-38, and then 44-50; is this maybe because React.createClass is deprecated?

Answer (score 3):

You need to stringify an object before storing it:

```
localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Then, when retrieving it, you just do

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'));
```

The reason for this is that everything is stored as a string, so it calls the .toString() method, which for objects returns [object Object]

**EDIT**
I noticed you said you did stringify the objects. I guess it would depend the format of the object then, but I haven't encountered any issue with not clearing storage beforehand.