# What is the difference between [object Object] and Object {key: value}?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm saving data in local storage, but having a hard time parsing/not parsing in the appropriate places to use the object properties when I need them, or stringify them when they need to be saved.

When the console logs the following (and I'm in chrome, so the key is purple and the value is red):

```
Object {foo: bar}
```

I'm able to access the properties correctly.

When the console logs

```
[object Object]
```

I can't access the properties. If this means it's a string, why can't I parse it? If it's already an object, why can't I access its properties?

**Edit**

The question I should have asked is: how do I convert this string to an object with which I can access properties etc?

Comment: That means it's a string, yes. You can’t parse it because the `ToString` of an object isn’t a serialization of the object (not all objects are serializable).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does \[object Object\] mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750225/what-does-object-object-mean)

Comment: What do you mean "parse it"? How do you parse the string "[object Object]" into anything meaningful? For localStorage, `JSON.stringify()` when setting, `JSON.parse()` when getting.

Comment: One is an object, the other used to be but isn't an object anymore.

Comment: possible duplicate? X/Y problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage

Comment: I am using `JSON.stringify()` to set and `JSON.parse()` to get, yes. What is serialization?

Comment: the conversion from one format to another

Comment: If you're using JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse(), how are you getting [object Object]? neither create that output.

Comment: Kevin B's possible duplicate was close, but the problem I'm having is using `JSON.stringify()` to save in localStorage and `JSON.parse()` when I get it, [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43661936/string-set-in-localstorage-gets-as-object

Comment: Per your edit... that's impossible. You instead must back track until you have an object to work with. Once it's in that string form, there's no going back.

Comment: @KevinB Have you looked at the link in my previous comment? Concerning storage, isn't the idea to stringify an object to place it in local storage, and then parse it back when you get it? Which strings can be parsed and which can't? Do I need to stringify and save the object differently?

Comment: I dunno, you haven't shown your code. per the question i linked, clearly using stringify and parse properly works. you must be doing something improperly.

Comment: per your link... i think there's more going on there than the OP presented.

Comment: here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asparism/Lr0foyLt/). you can replicate the problem by commenting and uncommenting the localStorage.clear() in the beginning.

Comment: per your fiddle... `localStorage.setItem("_asparism_"+this.props.name, theDish);` wut, theDish is... not something you should be putting in local storage. (toward the end)

Comment: @KevinB need to stringify before setting?

Comment: well, it's a component... not the kind of thing you'd put in localstorage. I don't quite understand what you were trying to do with that line.

Answer (score -1):

`[object Object]` is a string representation of the object, similar to calling `object.toString()`

To get a detailed log, use `dir()` (exclusive to Google Chrome Dev Tools)

[image]

- To stringify an object, use `JSON.stringify(object)`.
- To restore an object back from string, use `JSON.parse(string)`.

Comment: i found the answer to be not useful (as indicated by the downovote.)

Comment: or at best unclear. yes, json.stringify/parse should probably be used in the OP's scenario, but why?

Comment: Do I use console.dir(theObject) ? How would I then access the properties or convert it to an object?

Comment: you wouldn't, that's just a debugging tool. [object Object] is just a useless string, you can't gain anything out of it other than the fact that it *was* an Object until it was converted to a string.

Comment: @asparism you should access values just fine if that's an object. Use `dir()` to debug the case when you are not getting what you want.

Comment: @WearyAdventurer console.dir(theObject) returns the same string. It doesn't seem to be an object, it seems to be a string which for some reason can't be parsed into an object.

Comment: @asparism Try serializing the object with `JSON.stringify()` and see what it throws out. Where are you getting this object, what do you assign to it?

Comment: @WearyAdventurer `JSON.stringify()` logs "[object Object]". the problem is replicated in this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/asparism/Lr0foyLt/). You can comment and uncomment the localStorage.clear() at the beginning to see the issue.

Comment: @asparism There might be an issue with react. Do you absolutely need to use it?

Comment: After removing all of the extra junk, it works fine.

Comment: @WearyAdventurer I'd like to keep it, yes.

Comment: @KevinB By extra junk do you mean everything except the storage code?

Comment: @asparism yes. And to test it i commented out all the var a b c etc leaving just the .key(0) and .getItem(key).

Comment: @KevinB do you have a forked fiddle by chance? and thanks, i'll try to clean it up and see if it starts working.